# Could we create a psychopath?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

I am new here, so I apologize if this question violates any of the rules of this community. A question that has kept bugging me for few months is whether, we could alter the brain chemistry of a totally normal person to make him a psychopath/sociopath. The ethics of such a procedure is of course debatable just like whether we should extend life. But keeping aside the ethical considerations, is there any ongoing research on this topic? For instance, I have come across Kevin Dutton (British psychologist) and the fact that Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation can induce temporary psychopathic traits in an individual. I am not sure as to the validity of this. Is there any other such research going on and what is the status?

Comment: Project MK-ultra - so, not same as psychopath, but close = yep and it can be done much easier then Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKUltra#:~:text=One%201955%20MKUltra,perform%20physical%20activity.

Comment: @άνθρωπος - Please can you elaborate on your response and turn it into an answer? I am intrigued to know how a project similar to MK-ultra could create a psychopath/sociopath or similar. Plus, how would it be easier than TMS?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. You said that you have *"come across Kevin Dutton (British psychologist) and the fact that Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation can induce temporary psychopathic traits in an individual."* Could you please provide a link to this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.